# fillbetween not working in scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, scoping

I want to display three plots each stacked vertically. As shown below in the figure. Generated by the following code. But fillbetween is not working.

[image: WithScope]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \begin{axis}[
    % Axis Line Passing Through Middle
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    % X and Y labels
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$x(t) = x_{1}(t)x_{2}(t)$},
    % Positioning X and Y label
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=south,
    },
    % Fonts to be Tiny
    font=\tiny,
    % Abscissa Range
    xmin = -1.8,
    xmax = 1.8,
    % Ordinate Range
    ymin = -1,
    ymax = 1,
    % Extending Axis Range
    enlarge x limits = 0.15,
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    % Axis Line Style to be very thin
    axis line style = very thin,
    % Axis Line Style Color
    axis line style = {black!50!white},
    % Plot Dimension
    width=10cm,
    height=3.5cm,
    ]
    % Add plot from data file with cyan color and assigning it to path A
    \addplot[color = cyan,domain = -2:2,samples = 400,name path = 
    A,smooth]{cos(deg(2*pi*x))*cos(deg(3*pi*x))};

    % Reference path B for the domain 0 to 0.17 with value set to 0
    \addplot+[draw=none,name path = B, domain=0:1, mark=none] {0};

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
    \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and       
    B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0:0.17}];

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0.17 to 0.25
    \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0.17:0.25}];

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
    \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and 
    B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0.25:0.5}];

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
    \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0.5:0.75}];

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0.75 to 0.83
    \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and 
    B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0.75:0.83}];

    % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
    \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
    clip = {domain = 0.83:1}];

    % Placing Origin 0
    \node[] at (axis cs: -0.1,-0.35) {$0$};
    % Placing \cdots for continuing right side
    \node at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) [anchor=north east] {$\cdots$};
    % Placing \cdots for continuing left side
    \node at (axis cs:-2.2,0.3) [anchor=south west] {$\cdots$};
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=2.5cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$x_{2}(t)$},
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        font=\tiny,
        xmin = -1.8,
        xmax = 1.8,
        enlarge x limits = 0.15,
        enlarge y limits = 0.15,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        axis line style = {black!50!white},
        axis line style = very thin,
        width=10cm,
        height=3.5cm,
        ]
        \addplot[color = cyan,domain = -2:2,samples = 400,name path = 
        A,smooth]{cos(deg(2*pi*x))};

        % Placing Origin 0
        \node[] at (axis cs: -0.1,-0.35) {$0$};
        % Placing \cdots for continuing right side
        \node at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) [anchor=north east] {$\cdots$};
        % Placing \cdots for continuing left side
        \node at (axis cs:-2.2,0.3) [anchor=south west] {$\cdots$};
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=5cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$x_{1}(t)$},
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        font=\tiny,
        xmin = -1.8,
        xmax = 1.8,
        enlarge x limits = 0.15,
        enlarge y limits = 0.15,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        axis line style = {black!50!white},
        axis line style = very thin,
        width=10cm,
        height=3.5cm,
        ]
        \addplot[color = cyan,domain = -2:2,samples = 400,name path = 
        A,smooth]{cos(deg(3*pi*x))};

        % Placing Origin 0
        \node[] at (axis cs: -0.1,-0.35) {$0$};
        % Placing \cdots for continuing right side
        \node at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) [anchor=north east] {$\cdots$};
        % Placing \cdots for continuing left side
        \node at (axis cs:-2.2,0.3) [anchor=south west] {$\cdots$};
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Whereas if I'm not using scope fillbetween works as desired.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % Axis Line Passing Through Middle
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        % X and Y labels
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$x(t) = x_{1}(t)x_{2}(t)$},
        % Positioning X and Y label
        every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,
                },
        every axis y label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south,
                },
        % Fonts to be Tiny
        font=\tiny,
        % Abscissa Range
        xmin = -1.8,
        xmax = 1.8,
        % Ordinate Range
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        ytick = {\empty},
        % Extending Axis Range
        enlarge x limits = 0.15,
        enlarge y limits = 0.15,
        % Axis Line Style to be very thin
        axis line style = very thin,
        % Axis Line Style Color
        axis line style = {black!50!white},
        % Plot Dimension
        width=10cm,
        height=3.5cm,
        ]
        % Add plot from data file with cyan color and assigning it to path A
        \addplot[color = cyan,domain = -2:2,samples = 400,name path = 
        A,smooth]{cos(deg(2*pi*x))*cos(deg(3*pi*x))};


        % Reference path B for the domain 0 to 0.17 with value set to 0
        \addplot+[draw=none,name path = B, domain=0:1, mark=none] {0};

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
        \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and       
        B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0:0.17}];

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0.17 to 0.25
        \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0.17:0.25}];

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
        \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and 
        B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0.25:0.5}];

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
        \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0.5:0.75}];

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0.75 to 0.83
        \addplot+[yellow, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and 
        B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0.75:0.83}];

        % Fill area between path A and B for the domain 0 to 0.17
        \addplot+[red, fill opacity = 0.4] fill between[of = A and B,soft 
        clip = {domain = 0.83:1}];



        % Placing Origin 0
        \node[] at (axis cs: -0.1,-0.35) {$0$};

        % Plaacing \cdots for continuing
        \node at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) [anchor=north east] {$\cdots$};
        \node at (axis cs:-2.2,0.3) [anchor=south west] {$\cdots$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Without Scope]

Am I doing any mistake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because "scoping" is not allowed when layers are used which is true when you use `fill between`. As the PGFPlots manual (v1.15) states in [section 4.27.2 (on page 407)](http://ctan.mirrors.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=407)

> **Limitation: no environments or local TeX groups allowed.** Standard usages as within the examples of this manual will always work. But since the layer name configuration is essentially part of a pgf picture (at a low level), one cannot arbitrarily set them; pgf will complain if they
>   are changed within some nested TeX groups or LaTeX environments. Typically, you will never need to worry about this.
>
> In short, the following examples are forbidden because the axis is within locally nested groups.

which is followed by 3 examples. To circumvent this problem you could just move the `yshift` command to the `axis` options. This is part of my provided solution given below.

In addition you can heavily simplify your code by

- creating a style which is used for every `axis` environment, and
- by using the `split` option for your `fill between` code.

For details, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        my axis style/.style={
            % Axis Line Passing Through Middle
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            % X and Y labels
            xlabel={$t$},
            % Positioning X and Y label
            every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=west,
            },
            every axis y label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
                anchor=south,
            },
            % Fonts to be Tiny
            font=\tiny,
            % Abscissa Range
            xmin=-1.8,
            xmax=1.8,
            % Ordinate Range
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=1,
            % Extending Axis Range
            enlarge x limits=0.15,
            enlarge y limits=0.15,
            % Axis Line Style to be very thin
            axis line style=very thin,
            % Axis Line Style Color
            axis line style={black!50!white},
            % Plot Dimension
            width=10cm,
            height=3.5cm,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % moved common stuff here
            domain=-2:2,
            samples=201,
            mark=none,
            % moved stuff that is added to every plot here
            execute at begin axis={
                % Placing Origin 0
                \node[] at (axis cs: -0.1,-0.35) {$0$};
                % Placing \cdots for continuing right side
                \node at (axis cs:2.2,0.5) [anchor=north east] {$\cdots$};
                % Placing \cdots for continuing left side
                \node at (axis cs:-2.2,0.3) [anchor=south west] {$\cdots$};
            },
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        ylabel={$x(t)=x_{1}(t)x_{2}(t)$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        name=lower plot,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        % Add plot from data file with cyan color and assigning it to path A
        \addplot [color=cyan,name path=A]
            {cos(deg(2*pi*x))*cos(deg(3*pi*x))};

        % Reference path B for the domain 0 to 0.17 with value set to 0
        \addplot+ [draw=none,mark=none,name path=B,domain=0:1] {0};

        \addplot fill between [
            of=A and B,
            soft clip={domain=0:1},
            split,
            every odd segment/.style={
                red, fill opacity=0.4,
            },
            every even segment/.style={
                yellow, fill opacity=0.4,
            },
        ];
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        ylabel={$x_{2}(t)$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        name=middle plot,
        anchor=south,
        at={(lower plot.above north)},
        yshift=5pt,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot [color=cyan] {cos(deg(2*pi*x))};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        ylabel={$x_{1}(t)$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        name=upper plot,
        anchor=south,
        at={(middle plot.above north)},
        yshift=5pt,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot [color=cyan] {cos(deg(3*pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I'm getting error at line 56 with Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.15' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key. }

Comment: This was because of the line `compat=1.15` in the `\pgfplotsset` which I just removed. (I added this to use the Lua features which allowed faster compilation.) Most likely you have an older version of PGFPlots which causes this error message.

Comment: I tried the same after removing compat=1.15 in the \pgfplotsset. But still, the plots are same as that of mine without filling.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I was using the current CVS version of PGFPlots where [bug 139](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139) already is solved. So reducing the number of samples from 401 to 201 now gives the desired result (see my edited answer).