# pgfplots input axis settings from an external file

Tags: pgfplots, input, axis

I want to plot multiple figures with the same settings, but different content. I would then like to be able to change the settings in all plots at the same time.
To achieve this, I'd like to store the settings in their own file, so when it changes, the plots will all change!
Say I wan't to plot $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ (here only $\sin(x)$ is shown) I could then store my `xlabel` in the file with the settings, and the `ylabel` in the file making the figure.

It would then looks like the following:

settings.tex:

```
xlabel={$x$},
```

main.tex for the $\sin(x)$ plot, change every "sin" to "cos" and it would be the cos file:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            \input{settings.tex}
            ylabel={$y=\sin(x)$}
        ]
        \addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This however stuns LaTeX, and will not compile. If I move the `xlabel` to the main file, I get what I want:

[image]

The above is very much an MWE. I would offcourse like to use tens of settings across a multitude of figures, making it very tiresome to update the settings in every plot.

Comment: Therefore you can define you own **style**s as e.g. shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417423/95441.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks a lot, it works great ;-) Would you make an answer with a style in a `settings.tex` so I can close the question?

Comment: I hope it is ok for you, too, that I will close this question as duplicate and you could up-vote the answer in the link ...

Comment: That is certainly okay @StefanPinnow ;-)